# most frequent value in active record coloumn

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Just wanted to ask does anyone know how to find the 5 most frequent values in a model colomn for active record.

eg

```
Country.find(:name)
```

How would I find the top 5 most common countries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following

```
Country.group(:name).order('count_id DESC').limit(5).count(:id)
```